# How to fix Unit Testing - error: "Cannot read property 'parseUrl' of undefined"?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

For a component which uses a Service I'am writing a unit testing - spec file.

**function in the component:**

```
registerUser(email: string, pass: string) {
    if (!this.EMAIL_REGEXP.test(email)) {
        return false;
    } else if (!this.PASS_REGEXP.test(pass)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        this._backUpApiService.storeUserData(email, pass)
        .subscribe(
            (res) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringfy(res));
                ...
            },
            (err) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringfy(err));
                ...
            }
        );
    }
}
```

**method in the service:**

```
storeUserData(email:String, pass:String) {
    this.form = this._fbuilder.group({
        input: {
            user:{
                umail:email,
                upassword:pass
            }
        }
    });
    let formObj = this.form.getRawValue();
    let serializedObj = JSON.stringify(formObj);

    return this._http.post(url, serializedObj, this.options)
    .map(res => {
        res.json();
    })
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

**The spec file:**

```
it(`should call storeUserData on BackendApiService when registerUser is called with correct Credentials`, async(() => {

    let myService: BackendApiService = new BackendApiService();
    spyOn(myService, 'storeUserData').and.returnValue(Observable.of(myService));

    const emailOk = [
      'test@test.com',
      'test@test.co.uk',
    ];
    const passwordOk = '!cdRef2';

    let result = component.registerUser(this.emailOk, this.passwordOk);

    expect(myService.storeUserData).toHaveBeenCalled();

  }));
```

The issue is that the test failed and I keep getting the following: **`Cannot read property 'parseUrl' of undefined`**

Can it be that the function in spec file is expecting the **`URL`** for the Ajax Call in the Service function? I actually just want to test if the **`storeUserData`** function in the service is being called when the **`registerUser`** function in the component is called/invoked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe related to this one: https://github.com/MindscapeHQ/raygun4js/issues/126

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are getting a "Cannot read property 'parseUrl' of undefined" error seeing as your code doesn't contain any reference to parseUrl.

However I can see a couple of errors:

First storeUserData is not actually called from registerUser addUser is.

Second registerUser is expecting a string to be passed as for it's email and you are passing it an array of strings.

**Edit**

An additional observation:

Another place there is an error is that you are creating a new instance of your service as opposed to getting the instance of the service used by your component. You need to use:

```
const myService = TestBed.get(BackendApiService);
```

Then you will actually be spying on the instance of the service used by your component. This does of course presume that your service is getting injected into the constructor of your component.

If you get the spyOn working correctly then indeed you don't need to worry about what is going on in storeUserData as it will never be called. The only other place an error may come from is the constructor of your service. I've created Service stub classes to inject into my tests so that my service class dependencies don't cause problems. For you that might look like:

```
export class BackendApiServiceStub {
  storeUserData(email: String, pass: String) {
    return Observable.of([]);
  }
}
```

And then you need to substitute the stub for the real thing in the TestBed like so:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: BackendApiService, useClass: BackendApiServiceStub }
  ]
}).compileComponents();
```

That should stop any additional problems creeping into your test.

Comment: @lain: I think it has to do with the `serializedObj ` which a JSON object.
I did correct the the error regarding `registerUser`

Comment: And also I agree with the second notice regarding array. should be enough to check one valid Email and also wrong if the function is expecting as String and I'am passing an Array- My bad.